# DBContextFactory Issues with Blazor Server .Net 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, dbcontext

I saw a video that said in Blazor server you need to use DBContextFactory because if you just use DBContext it can cause issues. I verified that by reading Microsoft's documentation as well. I didn't have these issues though until I changed it to DBContextFactory. When I use DBContextFactory I am randomly getting the following issue [image] The database is being updated but when the next action is called it fails saying that it should have affected a row, but it didn't. Is this an issue with entity framework in Blazor or is this a DBContextFactory Issue?

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMOIClientService, MOIClientsService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


//builder.Services.AddScoped<IDialogService, DialogService>();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MOIDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

**MOIClientService**

```
public class MOIClientsService : IMOIClientService
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<MOIDBContext> _contextFactory;

        public MOIClientsService(IDbContextFactory<MOIDBContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }


        public async Task<List<Client>> GetClients()
        {
            using MOIDBContext db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            {
                var clientList = await db.Client.Include(i => i.FileList).ToListAsync();
                return clientList;
            }

        }

        public void AddClient(Client client)
        {
            using MOIDBContext db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            {
                db.Add(client);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obvious in your code.  The error suggests that you haven't added a record.  Write some logging to check the EntityEntry and output a check on client.

Adding, like getting, is normally an async operation, so try moving to an async method.

```cs
public async ValueTask<int> AddClientAsync(Client client)
{
    using var db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var entityEntry = db.Add(client);
    // result is the number of records affected by the change
    // it should always be 1
    var result = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with another method that was being called using entity framework. I was passing it a Model of something that had been slightly changed and it was causing all sorts of weird issues. All I had to do was refresh my model against the database and now all is working.